# Before interviewing at a grad school, how much background research should I do into its research groups?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, interview, austria

I was recently invited for on-campus Interviews at Austria‘s top graduate school. I picked 5 Group Leaders, of which 3 will eventually conduct the interview.

Naturally, I’ll be prepared for any and all questions regarding my previous thesis, internships and classes.

**Questions:**

1. How much reading should I do about the research of the groups I’m interested in?
2. Can I expect detailed questions regarding their latest publications, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience interviewing was in the US, so it might or might not apply to you in Austria.

None of the schools where I interviewed expected me to know the details of their latest work. I read a few of their recent papers so I had some idea what the groups did and I could have an intelligent conversation with professors and other students. It seemed to go well.

Good luck!